# WCF won't trace non-soap reply messages

Tags: wcf, trace

Is there a way to have WCF tracing do a Message Log Trace even when the response message is not a valid SOAP message?  Right now it just throws an exception that the server did not provide a meaningful reply and stops tracing.

I need to see the reply though as it has information that is useful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable message logging then set the attribute `logMalformedMessages=true`.

> Malformed messages are messages that are rejected by the WCF stack at any stage of processing. Malformed messages are logged as-is: encrypted if they are so, with non-proper XML, and so on. **`maxSizeOfMessageToLog`** defined the size of the message to be logged as CDATA. By default, **`maxSizeOfMessageToLog`** is equal to 256K. For more information about this attribute, see the Other Options section.
>
> [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks so much for this.. I'm not sure if I should be more amazed that I missed that in the documentation or that it took so long for someone else to point it out :)